# Xamarin.Forms:SSO Using PingFederate

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory, pingfederate

Can anyone help me in implementing SSO using PingFederate in Xamarin.Forms.

The Pingfederate authorizes against Azure Active Directory. The PingFederate Client Credential Grant Type is required to be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too involved of a solution to provide here, but PingFederate offers a detailed guide that describes how to do this. https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/O365IG20_sm_integrationGuide/page/O365IG_c_usingAzureAdConnect.html

For the SSO portion of it in AAD you can follow this Azure Samples guide and accompanying repository: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect

My colleague and I made a YouTube tutorial on SSO which may be of use. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MohaxN6fsDs&t=16s